# calculate TF-IDF in pyton 2.7 (with three line of code). Does this code work?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate the tfidf value on a corpus of about 7000 documents.
Searching on internet, I founded a lot of examples (many of them locked when I tried to create the uniquewords matrix for each document). The only to seems to works is this code below

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
x = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
df_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(x.toarray(), columns=tfidf.get_feature_names())
print(df_tfidf)
```

Assuming the following corpus

```
corpus = [
 'This is the first document.',
 'This document is the second document.',
 'And this is the third one.',
 'Is this the first document?']
```

It produced this output:

[image]

This code works also with my case and in fact it produce a matrix with 7180 rows and 10390 columns. But I'm not sure if it's correct. In your opinions, is this a valid solution for calculate tfidf for a set of documents ?

---

p.s: can I insert the link of guide that I followed ?

Comment: why do you think it is incorrect? To me, it looks correct

Comment: No particular reason, but it seemed too simple to me. All the other solutions I saw there was much more code also much more complex

Comment: This is the correct way as explained on [sklearn website](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)  too

Comment: @KimTang Only if the code is known to be correct. Code where there are doubts whether it actually performs the way it should, is off-topic for Code Review (see their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: @KimTang The code in the above post is not the OP's and so is off-topic on Code Review - "I founded a lot of examples[...]. The only to seems to works is this code below"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct approach for calculating the tf-idf matrix.

You are using

```
x = tfidf.fit_transform(corpus)
```

which first fits your `TfidfVectorizer` to your corpus and then transforms the corpus accordingly, so that you get your tf-idf matrix as the `x`